# How best to learn OOP concepts/principles practically?

Tags: object-oriented

I wanted to learn object oriented programming language, I don't want it for any purpose just to know the whole concept of OOP.
So can anyone tell me which language I should start learning?

Comment: What languages do you know already?

Comment: C, VB.NET, and C++ but not the OOP part

Comment: pick VB.NET then

Comment: No, I dont want VB.NET I want you guys to help me choose between Java, C++, Python etc...

Comment: You want to practically learn something for no purpose?

Comment: @Jeff O, I updated the question title to include "practially" since lamia wants to learn using a language.

Comment: what I mean is I did not want to use OOP at the moment.

Comment: Here's some more:
From the category of “do not even think to do this” here are some bad examples of code encountered: http://centraladvisor.com/it/oop-what-are-the-best-practices-in-oop

Comment: Try [Elegant Objects](http://www.yegor256.com/elegant-objects.html) book

Answer (score 13):

Some further suggestions:

- The best book I've ever read on OOP bar none is Bertrand Meyer's [Object Oriented Software Construction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136291554).  It's not an 'easy' read in that you'll need to think hard in places.  But it does the best job I've seen of explaining OO principles.
- As for languages: I'd stay away from C++.  Just too big for learning purposes.  If you want a language that will really help you understand OO (as opposed to one that you would write mainstream apps in / get a job using) then look at smalltalk.  Or Eiffel (the language in Meyer's book above).
- If you want a language that's a bit more mainstream but still faithfully supports OO principles then Python is a good bet.  Java & C# are decent too if you want static typing.

One word of caution though: the language won't teach you OO.  It can only help (or hinder) in how well it supports OO concepts.  Learning OO is really about learning to *think* in OO terms.  For that I'd come back to Meyer's book.

hth.

Comment: The other things in C++ are *important*. It's *important* to know about virtual inheritance. It's *important* to know about strong compile-time generic support, and it's *important* to know about value vs reference. Going for something like Java is just going "LA LA LA I CAN'T HEAR YOU THIS IS THE ONLY WAY TO DO IT".

Comment: yes and no.  The OP's question was about learning which implies basics first. I'm not convinced C++ is among the contenders as the most suitable _learning_ language.  That said: Meyer covers generics & value vs reference anyway, albeit as more advanced topics.  He also goes into co- and contra-variance, in latter parts of the book.  But he sets out the basics first.  (And Eiffel is statically typed btw).

Comment: I'm not going to agree or disagree with a recommendation of Eiffel, since I've never used or even seen or read anything about it. However, I absolutely will disagree with any recommendation for Java and C#, as I said.

Answer (score 12):

You can learn any of the object oriented languages such as C++, Java, C# etc. to try out OOPS.

If you really want to learn OOP, you need to think beyond languages and understand that it is a paradigm that helps mangae complexity involved in software programs just like how we manage them in  this real world. Then learn the basic concepts in OO like Polymorphism, Inheritance, Encapsulation **(PIE)** etc

There are good books around too-Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications (2nd Edition) by Grady Booch

Also, you may try out  blogs like this which i found is simple enough to start with- [fascinatingoops.com](http://fascinatingoops.blogspot.com/2007/05/oop-and-oo-thinking.html)

Answer (score 3):

You want to learn OOP? One answer - Smalltalk.

It is an elegant language and is OO to the core. You will learn OOP from the beginning and won't be hampered by all the other distractions that other languages manage to incorporate.

Smalltalk wins. And there are some good free e-books available too (see: [Stephane Ducasse](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks.html))

Answer (score 3):

You would have to learn C++, or maybe one of the forefathers like Smalltalk. C++ offers a clean separation between concepts like object orientation, memory management, and reference vs value, and it has strong generic support.

Don't learn Java or a .NET language like C#. When you learn a language like Java, then you learn things like "Objects are always on the heap and are always references", which is only true for Java and absolutely not true for OOP in general. This conflation of concepts (object-orientation, memory management, reference vs value) is very dangerous for a first language, because once you get them stuck in your head, it can be very hard to get them back out. C# is *somewhat* better in this regard but not much. In addition, they can have a high tendency to teach "Inheritance is a hammer and everything is a nail" with weak generic programming support.

Comment: This is very true. I have never though of this before, actually when dealing with a language that is very focused on OOP and tries to solve everything with OOP you will never learn which problems are not really suited to OOP.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to learn OOP concepts is to write more and more code and get it reviewed often. Practice maketh a good programmer.

Think real world scenarios, define a problem statement - solve it in code and get it reviewed. You can always get the help from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for reviews :)

Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

Steps

1. Learn what they mean.
2. Learn how to implement them.
3. Take a project to develop, choose your language [which should have OOPS principle integrated like VB.NET or C# or C++ or java etc]
4. Think about how you can **simplify** the project logic by OOPS. [Note: Don't just implement OOPS because you wanted to have them, they should solve your purpose]
5. Don't forget: *You will learn from your mistakes too*.

Answer (score 0):

My first contact to the OO world was C++, which was not a bad start. But I improved a lot when learning Python. The difference comes from the languages: trying out ideas ('how can I solve this problem in a OO fashion ?')  in C++ needs more code to be written and includes much more pitfalls than trying out the same idea in Python. So I would recommend Python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should look into another language while trying to learn OOP. To me, it's easier to grasp the theory and then learning to apply it if I can relate to something I already know. Figuring out a new syntax just gets in the way.

You can start with any OOP book. Again, I'd get one in my language of choice. Reading a book on refactoring (OOP Style) helped me in the application of OOP. I took an existing project (No distraction from requirements gathering) and found new ways to improve it. It wasn't just OOP for OOP sake. Then you can learn how to do it from start to finish on a new project. The logic here is you won't always get it right from the start. If you can recognize where it is appropriate, you'll be better off. Like most things it won't solve every problem.

There are definite limitations with some languages. If your goal is to be the master of multiiple inheritance, .NET is out.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go against the conventional thinking here and suggest that the easiest languages for *using* OOP aren't necessarily the best languages for *learning* it.  I was first exposed to OOP with C++, but I didn't "get" it until reading Larry Wall's Camel book chapter on OOP with Perl.  For some reason I had trouble grasping the difference between classes and objects until having to explicitly *bless* an object into a class.  I didn't truly understand the underlying implementation of OOP until doing it in C with GObject, where none of those details are hidden from you. I didn't truly understand the best practices until taking a corporate class that was language-agnostic.  It's a very big topic, and you have to find ways to learn it that work best for *you*.